# How to get the URL of a community builder page

Tags: community

I have created a page in community builder and configured an URL for this page. (see image)
[image]

When I use this URL to make a redirection I get a page not found error.

The Url I end up with is this: https://sandboxname-customername.cs83.force.com/communityname/choose-current-dealer

What I did now is add an "s" in the url because this seems to be there for all URLs.

The Url I end up with now is this: https://sandboxname-customername.cs83.force.com/communityname/s/choose-current-dealer

And this works.

Now the question is if it is safe to hardcode an url like this or if it is likely to change in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL's are subject to change in lightning communities, however, this does not happen overnight.

These update(s) usually happen with [Lightning Community Template Updates](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=communities_update_template.htm&type=5):

[image]

So, as long as you don't update your template, if you hardcoded a url, it should not break.

Comment: thx, good enough for me. Do you happen to know where the "s" may come from?

Comment: Site.com site’s append /s/ to the URL, consider it a default

Comment: The other scenario is that when you deploy a community to a new environment then the URL changes, e.g. sanboxes will be on different nodes like cs80, cs88 or production will have the different base URL.